# Shared Preferences in Android using check box

Tags: java, android

I have a preference file which uses checkboxes and i want to use it to determine when it been checked or not. However in the code itself, there is already a boolean statement. please check this:

```
String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;



    Boolean enteringRegion = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

    if (enteringRegion){
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "entering");
    }
    else{
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "exiting");
    }


boolean enteringRegions = prefs.getBoolean("alarm_entering", true);
     boolean exitRegion = prefs.getBoolean("alarm_exiting", false);
```

Comment: Can you explain what this code is supposed to do, and what isn't working for you? Thanks. If you are confused about the second argument of the getBoolean() method, it is the default value that is returned only if the selected key is not found in the preferences.

Comment: I want the code to be able to use an If statement to get the user input: If (enteringRegion == true) { } it should run the code above. However this does not work as there is already an if statement above. don't really understand what to do. Many thanks

Comment: It looks like you are getting information from three separate places. First, you are getting the boolean extra from the intent. Two, you are reading the shared preference "alarm_entering". Three, you are reading the shared preference "alarm_exiting". What are these three different inputs?

Comment: Yeah,what I  actually wanted to do is to use the alarm_entering to call the if enteringRegion and alarm_exiting for the exiting but because the intent already has a boolean enteringRegion there is no way I can use another boolean statement to reference it and thats where am confused

Comment: Honestly, I still cannot understand what it is you are trying to do. Are you trying to set a preference, or get the current state of an existing preference? Is the check box part of a `CheckBoxPreference`? In that case, the preference should be automatically updated. Are you trying to trigger some code to occur when the preference changes? Try to clearly explain what you want to occur, and what actions by the user should trigger this.

Comment: What I want to do is to use two checkboxes to determine if a device is entering into a region but by default the location manager get it and I want to have control over it such that it uses the checkbox preference to determine when to respond or not